# Flink: How to configure Flink such that the Taskmanagers auto restart after a failure?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

How to configure Flink such that the Taskmanagers auto restart after a failure ?

Comment: Have you check the [configuration docs](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.10/ops/config.html#fault-tolerance)?

Comment: @ArvidHeise Is defining a restart strategy really enough? E.g., consider a standalone cluster where the machine hosting the TM has failed.

Comment: @ArvidHeise restart-strategy is for restarting a job from a checkpoint. I am asking about auto restart of Task manager itself not the job.

Comment: Then please add your environment. It's different for the kind of deployments.

Comment: I think Flink HA is independent of environment. My question is Flink specific. Say a local cluster on windows.The question is pretty straight forward and so should be the answer. I see that HA provides robustness for Jobmanager via zookeeper. But what about taskmanager. So I hope it is clear enough.

Comment: Flink HA is not independent of environment as you can also see by @DavidAnderson's answer. The more details you provide on your setup, the more tailored can the answer be.

Answer (score 1):

On [yarn](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/ops/deployment/yarn_setup.html) and kubernetes Flink has a native resource manager (`YarnResourceManager` and `KubernetesResourceManager`) that will arrange for the requested number of slots to be available. In other environments you'll need to use cluster-framework-specific mechanisms to take care of this yourself.

Note that for k8s, only session clusters are supported by this new, more [active mode](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/ops/deployment/native_kubernetes.html) implemented by `KubernetesResourceManager`. Job clusters still need to be managed in the old fashioned way, as described in the [docs](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/ops/deployment/kubernetes.html).

And then there are managed Flink environments where these details are taken care of for you -- e.g., Ververica Platform or Kinesis Data Analytics.